# Independence question

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr F,\mathbb P)$, $A_1$, $A_2$, and $B$ are such events that

- $A_1$ and $B$ are independent;
- $A_2$ and $B$ are independent.

Does it necessarily follow that $A_1\cap A_2$ and $B$ are independent? If not, is there a simple counterexample?

Answer (score 2):

OK, of course not. Let $(\Omega,\mathscr F,\mathbb P)$ be the standard dice-rolling space and
\begin{align*}
A_1=&\,\{1,2,3\},\\
A_2=&\,\{3,4,5\},\\
B=&\,\{2,4\}.
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(A_1)=&\,1/2,\\
\mathbb P(A_2)=&\,1/2,\\
\mathbb P(B)=&\,1/3,\\
\mathbb P(A_1\cap B)=&\,\mathbb P(\{2\})=1/6=\mathbb P(A_1)\,\mathbb P(B),\\
\mathbb P(A_2\cap B)=&\,\mathbb P(\{4\})=1/6=\mathbb P(A_2)\,\mathbb P(B),
\end{align*}
but
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(A_1\cap A_2\cap B)=\mathbb P(\varnothing)=0\neq1/18=\mathbb P(A_1\cap A_2)\,\mathbb P(B).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Take $X,Y$ to be two independent uniform random variables on $\mathbb{Z}_2$; and let $A_1=\mathbf{1}_{\{X=1\}}$, $A_2=\mathbf{1}_{\{Y=1\}}$, and , $B=\mathbf{1}_{\{X+Y=1\}}$. This will give you a counterexample, as $X$ is independent of $X+Y$ (and $Y$ is independent of $X+Y$ as well), but if the event $A_1\cap A_2$ holds ($X=Y=1$) then $B$ does not (as $X+Y=0$).